# The difference between High energy SUSY and low energy SUSY

Tags: particle-physics, supersymmetry, symmetry-breaking, large-hadron-collider

In the literature and comments, I have met two pieces of jargon:
Low energy SUSY,
High energy SUSY

I'm confused about the technical and well-defined conceptual differences between the two type of Supersymmetry?

Of course one such difference should be the scale at which SUSY is broken, but I have no idea how high and low are distingushed formally and how they differ fundamentally from each other?

For example, I read a comment due to Peter West: that LHC can only rule out low energy SUSY which is different matter from high energy SUSY.